# i18n with Hogan.js

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, hogan.js

I just started with node.js and express.js. As server-side templating framework I picked Hogan.js. I am now trying to find out how I can do i18n with Hogan.js, and I found some information [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263601/1059357). It seems that you always have to pass in the i18n function together with the context of the view. Is it possible to configure this or set this up at a single place in the application? It seems very cumbersome if I have to do this for each and every view separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Express-lingua](https://github.com/akoenig/express-lingua) which seems to perfectly match your needs.

Comment: If you use that after rendering you essentially render twice, for simple i18n there really is no need, and for the complex i18n like pluralization i see no examples

Answer (score 0):

wrap the render function of hogan if you must

```
var origional = Hogan.template.prototype.render;
Hogan.template.prototype.render = function (context, partials, indent) {
    context['i18n'] = function () {
        return function () {
            return 'i18n';
        };
    };
    return origional.call(this, context, partials, indent);
};
```